# JavaScript document.createElement("a") problem with a.href attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Is this behaviour normal when creating a link with `document.createElement("a")` ?

```
function updateUl(newVal){
    let a = document.createElement("a")
    let newListItem = document.createElement("li")

    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newVal))
    console.log(newVal) //output: "www.google.com"
    a.href = newVal
    console.log(a.href) //output: "http://127.0.0.1:5500/www.google.com"
    a.target = "_blank"
    newListItem.appendChild(a)
    ulEl.appendChild(newListItem)
}
```

Then clearly when I click on the link I get a *page not found* error.

What's going on?

Comment: The `href` property setter is relative by default. `www.google.com` is a path-relative URL. Try an absolute URL instead: `"https://www.google.com"` or a protocol-relative one: `"//www.google.com"`.

Answer (score 1):

Without a protocol, it's assumed to be a route on the current page. Add the `https://` protocol to make it navigate.

```js
function updateUl(newVal){ // pass in as "https://www.google.com"
    let a = document.createElement("a")
    let newListItem = document.createElement("li")

    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newVal))
    console.log(newVal) //output: "https://www.google.com"
    a.href = newVal
    console.log(a.href) //output: "https://www.google.com"
    a.target = "_blank"
    newListItem.appendChild(a)
    ulEl.appendChild(newListItem)
}
```

or add it dynamically

```js
function updateUl(newVal){
    if (!newVal.startsWith("http://") && !newVal.startsWith("https://") {
        newVal = `https://{newVal}`;
    }
    let a = document.createElement("a")
    let newListItem = document.createElement("li")

    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newVal))
    console.log(newVal) //output: "https://www.google.com"
    a.href = newVal
    console.log(a.href) //output: "https://www.google.com"
    a.target = "_blank"
    newListItem.appendChild(a)
    ulEl.appendChild(newListItem)
}
```